# Capturing date manipulation within a 30 day period

Tags: android, date

I kindly need your help with capturing date manipulation. Please note that as you read on all the timestamps mentioned are form systems time and not from internet time plus I'm not permitted to use internet time in any way.

Essentially I have two timestamps (which include the date), one being the current system time and the second being a date fetched from a timestamp database which was the download timestamp for a file. In addition my app is required to download this file every 30 days

So for example:
TIMESTAMP FROM DB OR LAST DOWNLOAD DATE: 25/02/2012
CURRENT DATE: 15/03/2012
NEXT DOWNLOAD DATE will be on: 27/03/2012.

My challenge is that I want to stop/capture manipulation of the date within this 30 day window, so lets say the user realizes the app will update on 27/03/2012 he goes into his/her date and time settings and keeps rewinding the time in order never to allow the date from getting to the 27/03/2012 e.g.he rewinds the CURRENT DATE which is 15/03/2012 to 03/03/2012 meaning he "went 12 days back into time".

Any ideas/suggestions?

ANY ASSISTANCE IS APPRECIATED !!!

Hi Class Stacker, below is my attempt to create the timer but i'm slightly unsure where to place the check as you proposed. I've placed pseudocode where i think i should be running the check in the timer.

Here's my AlarmManagerActivity:

```
public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity {

 private AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver alarm;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        alarm = new AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Override
 protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
 }

public void startRepeatingTimer(View view) {
     Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
     if(alarm != null){
      alarm.SetAlarm(context);
     }else{
      Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }
 }
```

And here's my BroadCast Receiver:

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver");
     //Acquire the lock
     wl.acquire();

     //You can do the processing here.
     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

     if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
      //Make sure this intent has been sent by the one-time timer button.
      msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
     }
     Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
     msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

     Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     // SHOULD THE CODE TO CHECK SYSTEM TIME AGAINST THE CORRECT TIME BE PLACED HERE ??
     // CURRENTLY I'M DISPLAYING A TOAST
     // THANKS FOR ANY HELP

     //Release the lock
     wl.release();
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //After after EVERY HR
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 30 , pi);
}
```

}

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to monitor [`android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED) and [`android.intent.action.TIME_SET`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) by a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), but after having played around with them a bit, I wouldn't rely on them -- if your app is moved to the SD card, it will not receive any events right after boot until the SD card is mounted, for example.

Running a timer (e.g. hourly) via [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and having an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) match the expected time against the current system time would be more secure, in particular if you only need to know *whether* it happened. I wouldn't wake up the device, though, because all you need to know is whether the time was set to the past while the device was not sleeping.

If you find a system time greater than the expected time that's safe.

Just my spontaneous thoughts.

Comment: Hi Class Stacker, thanks for the swift reply. As I look into what you proposed what of storing each time the app is run and then checking if the difference between each stored run time and the current system time is zero, hence if CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME - EACH_RUN_TIME_STORED_IN_DB is equal to ZERO then the user has attempted the manipulation of CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME. My issue with this is if the user runs the app severally on the same day the difference between CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME and EACH_RUN_TIME_STORED_IN_DB will be zero meaning it looks like the user attempted manipulation when this isn't so

Comment: Not sure I understand you. First, excuse me for not being clear enough. I would let the IntentService run all the time, nut just during times when the app runs. I forgot to explain how to start it initially. But anyhow. The IntentService would be triggered e.g. every hour and it would access the last seen time stamp, and see what the delta to the system time is. If it is _less than an hour_ (including even negative results), the system time has been set to some point in the past. No?

Comment: Hi Class Stacker, I've adjusted my message and created the timer but was confused as to where in the timer I should place the check to calculate the difference between the current timestamp and the last run timestamp

Comment: @AMonari You surprise me. I was expecting more of a conceptual discussion. It's not even clear to me whether my suggestion works for you, because you need the IntentService to run after boot for this to make sense. -- Regardding your code, I got the impression you did not yet understand how BroadcastReceivers and IntentServices work. I can't help you right now. I can sure have another look at it later but it would be great if you re-read the documentation and study some examples until then.